# How can I make Chrome remember pinned tabs across multiple computers?

Tags: google-chrome

Is it possible to make Google Chrome remember my pinned tabs?

I'd like it so that whenever I synchronize my settings into a new Google Chrome, I could get the pin tabs I normally have on my notebook's Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, this is not a feature of Google Chrome. It sounds like a great idea! [You can suggest it to Google](http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/static.py?page=suggestions.cs.).